# Zend Framework using regular mysql select call

Tags: zend-db, zend-framework

Is there a way to use a regular mysql select statement with Zend Framework without having to use Zend_Db::factory

Code below is in my Model classes which extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

I can currently do this (which works):

```
    $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'dbuser',
                'password' => 'dbuserpass',
                'dbname' => "somedbname"
            ));

    $select = "SELECT iv.* 
                FROM image_variations AS iv
                LEFT JOIN images AS i ON (i.image_id = iv.image_id)
                LEFT JOIN product_images AS pi ON (pi.image_id = iv.image_id)
                WHERE pi.pid = '$pid'
                && iv.image_type_id = '$image_type_id' ";

    $stmt = $db->query($select);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $rows;
```

I would like to do this:

```
    $select = "SELECT iv.* 
                FROM image_variations AS iv
                LEFT JOIN images AS i ON (i.image_id = iv.image_id)
                LEFT JOIN product_images AS pi ON (pi.image_id = iv.image_id)
                WHERE pi.pid = '$pid'
                && iv.image_type_id = '$image_type_id' ";

    $stmt = $this->query($select);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $rows;
```

So I dont always have to define db variables in each method and have mysql passwords all over the place. Is there a way to use $this instead of having to instantiate a new $db Zend_DB Factory??

Comment: figured out a way to do it, will post when I am allowed in 5 hours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. The solution is not very elegant buts works and is portable.

My setup consists of multiple DBs, so in Bootstrap.php I have:

```
protected function _initDatabase() {
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    $resource->init();

    Zend_Registry::set('db', $resource->getDb('db'));
    Zend_Registry::set('shopdb', $resource->getDb('shopdb'));
}
```

In Application.ini

```
resources.multidb.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.multidb.db.host = 127.0.0.1
resources.multidb.db.username = user
resources.multidb.db.password = userpassword
resources.multidb.db.dbname = dbone
resources.multidb.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.multidb.db.default = true


resources.multidb.shopdb.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.multidb.shopdb.host = 127.0.0.1
resources.multidb.shopdb.username = user
resources.multidb.shopdb.password = userpassword
resources.multidb.shopdb.dbname = dbtwo
resources.multidb.shopdb.isDefaultTableAdapter = false
```

in index.php

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/application.ini");
Zend_Registry::set('settings', $config);
```

Then (the not very elegant bit) in Models add an init() method

```
protected $db;

public function init() {
    $settings = Zend_Registry::get('settings');
    $adapter = $settings->production->resources->multidb->shopdb->adapter;
    $params = array(
        'host' => $settings->production->resources->multidb->shopdb->host,
        'username' => $settings->production->resources->multidb->shopdb->username,
        'password' => $settings->production->resources->multidb->shopdb->password,
        'dbname' => $settings->production->resources->multidb->shopdb->dbname,
    );
    $this->db = Zend_Db::factory("$adapter", $params);
}
```

And then you can use $this->db in other methods in the Model class, eg:

```
public function getProductImages($pid, $image_type_id) {

    $select = "SELECT iv.* 
                FROM image_variations AS iv
                LEFT JOIN images AS i ON (i.image_id = iv.image_id)
                LEFT JOIN product_images AS pi ON (pi.image_id = iv.image_id)
                WHERE pi.pid = '$pid'
                && iv.image_type_id = '$image_type_id' ";

    $stmt = $this->db->query($select);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $rows;
}
```

It works but it still seems like there should be an easier way...